# Amphp parallel adding lots of amp-parallel sock files in php-fpm tmp folder

Tags: php, amphp

I am using the following code to submit workers into the queue and then run them with Task.

```
$executions = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    // FetchTask is just an example, you'll have to implement
    // the Task interface for your task.
    $executions[$url] = Worker\submit(new FetchTask($url));
}

// Each submission returns an Execution instance to allow two-way
// communication with a task. Here we're only interested in the
// task result, so we use the Future from Execution::getFuture()
$responses = Future\await(array_map(
    fn (Worker\Execution $e) => $e->getFuture(),
    $executions,
));
```

However, I see a lot of amp-parallel-*.sock files in php-fpm tmp directory and it appears to me that there is no clean-up for them.

Is that intended? When and how do these clean-up?

Comment: What have you tried so far to learn more about? Having this for 48h under observation, what has changed since then? How many files are being created how fast? Are files being deleted over time? How did you install it? How did you configurate it? What is the PHP version your're using and how is it configured for amphp? Your code looks incomplete, what is $urls?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the reason, it uses stream_socket_client to open a socket channel:
https://github.com/amphp/parallel/blob/1.x/lib/Context/Parallel.php#L188

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  (SO), Leandro! Please note that this is not an answer, but should be a comment. It might get deleted therefore. I see your good intentions, though, but please take a read here: [Why do we need 50 reputation to make comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252133/367456). Let me know if you've got any questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).